# Multiple components on a single page

Tags: component, module, extensions, custom-component

Is it possible to show multiple components on a single page in joomla?

I have 2 menu items, each one shows a different component, i want to show them both on the same page, is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components aren't really meant to be rendered more than once per request. Your best bet would be to make separate requests. Wrapper component and module can be used to display the page using an `iframe`.

Or you can retrieve the page in PHP using HTTP library. There is Components Anywhere plugin which uses this method https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/components-anywhere/.

Comment: I tried with iframe but it showed me the entire page inside the wrapper recursively, surely i miss something, i'll try with this extension, seems exactly what i was looking for, thank you

Comment: Add `tmpl=component` parameter to the URL to show only component area.